# images displaying in a site is not looking responsive

Tags: rwd

we are using follwing code to display images in this site:

http://demo1.kidsdial.com/

you can see 4 images below "slideshow" images but it's not looking responsive.

means in mobiles and tabs it's not arranged properly

means in smaller screen monitors, it's not displaying properly.

please help me what code changes I have to do to make it responsive?

Comment: Do you need output in this way?? http://i57.tinypic.com/zvslra.jpg

Comment: yes, thiat is awesome......

Comment: Ok give me some time to write CSS for you .

Comment: sure, take your time.... thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: Before that can you clarify me as you said 4 images but I can only see three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly add `<div class="image1">` above the four images theme it will be like this.Remove `inline styles for images`.

```
   <div class="image1">
      <img alt="" src="http://demo1.kidsdial.com/media/wysiwyg/topcategory1.jpg">
      <img alt="" src="http://demo1.kidsdial.com/media/wysiwyg/topoffers1.jpg"> 
      <img alt="" src="http://demo1.kidsdial.com/media/wysiwyg/topoffers2.jpg">
      <img alt="" src="http://demo1.kidsdial.com/media/wysiwyg/em0113/topoffers3.jpg">
    </div>
```

now add this **CSS** in `@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px)`

```
.image1 > img {
  height: 143px !important;
  max-width: 169px !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

in `@media screen and (max-width:1024px)`

```
.image1 > img {
  height: 143px !important;
  max-width: 231px !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

in `@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:767px)`

```
.image1 > img {
  height: 143px !important;
  max-width: 160px !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
}
```